# Problem with Unorganized content on page

Tags: views, taxonomy-terms

So I am not familiar with Drupal at all and need help. I am a graphic designer and trying to change the order of the layout on one of my pages. We had a developer design and organize our site but she screwed up the organization somehow.

How can I reorganize image on a page again? I tried going through Administrator > content > then I re-published the content in order but it did not work. [image]

[image]

I've added an image so you can see my problem. Basically I'm having to manually drag the items in order but row weights but wanted to know if I can somehow organize them by title name and refresh the page to fix the problem. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Since you tagged your question with "Views", I assume your screenprint is created via a *view*. And the view itself relates to some sort of *entities* like nodes, products, whatever.

If that's the case, decide about the "sort field" that you want to use in your view, and adapt it to fit your needs. If you cannot find any appropriate field that you want to use for such sorting, then just add an extra field (named something like *sequence nr*, and like an integer of say 4 digits). Then edit each of your entities to assign a relevant sequence nr, and use that as the sort field for your view.

BTW, this is true for pretty much any Drupal release.

PS: as per the "*drag the item*" in your question, it could well be that you're using the "[DraggableViews](https://www.drupal.org/project/draggableviews)" module to create such view.